# Wallet Objects API Java client library GoogleCredential lifetime

Tags: android-pay

With the Wallet Objects Java client library, can the GoogleCredential object be reused throughout the application lifetime, or is it intended for 1-time use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GoogleCredential object is intended to be reused for the application lifetime.  It will transparently handle storing auth tokens and renewing expired tokens for you.  To explicitly request a new access token you can refresh it with:

credential.refreshToken();

and get it with

credential.getAccessToken();